# Rails form protection questions, hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, security, bots

I have a live rails website and I want to have a form with a lot of fields on it. I have set up validations and allowed formatting for every field. I've tested it quite a bit and it seems to catch anything I throw at it.
I think it's almost ready to go live, but I want to quadruple check if there's anything else I should do to protect it. My site has a low volume of visitors, but I want it to be a safe as possible. I'd like to avoid using a captcha if I can. I've read that you can use a hidden field to protect forms against bots. 
Do people recommend this instead of using a captcha, or even using it with a captcha?

my form is really standard:

```
<% form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should whitelist a list of attributes that the user is allowed to edit in your model using [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002281)

Answer (score 0):

Write tests/specs for your models/controllers/views?